# How to correctly fetch data from firebase using where clauses and custom filters from firebase using flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to fetch data using

```
Stream<List<User>> getUsers(User user) {
    return _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        // .where('interestedIn', isEqualTo: _selectInterest(user))
        .snapshots()
        .map((snap) {
      return snap.docs.map((doc) => User.fromSnapshot(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
```

The filter used in the where clause is as follows

```
  _selectInterest(User user) {
    if (user.interestPreference == null) {
      return ['HIRING', 'WORK'];
    }
    return user.interestPreference;
  }
```

In firebase I store interestPreference as an Array with 'HIRING' as the only element in the current user's data, when I try to fetch users with 'HIRING' in their interestedIn which is a string I dont get any data. But when I hardcode the where clause as

```
.where('interestedIn', isEqualTo: 'HIRING')
```

I get the data, Can anyone help me solve my dilemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that last query, it sounds like the `interestedIn` field in your database is a single string value, like `interestedIn: "HIRING"`.

Your current query returns documents where `interestedIn` is an array with exactly the two values you specify, so `interestedIn: ['HIRING', 'WORK']`

If you want to return all documents where interested in is either `"HIRING"` or `"WORK"`, you can [use an `IN` condition](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any):

```
.where('interestedIn', whereIn: ['HIRING', 'WORK'])
```

Or with your helper function:

```
.where('interestedIn', whereIn: _selectInterest(user))
```